# elastic search searching case insensitive hyphens whitecaps

Tags: elasticsearch, whitespace, case-insensitive

I would like to search for a word or words which consists of hyphens, whitecaps and to be case insensitive.

Here is the index structure:

```
body' => array(
  'settings' => array(
    "analysis" => array(
      "analyzer" => array(
        "default" => array(
          "type" => "custom",
          'tokenizer' => "whitespace",
          "filter" => array("lowercase")
        ),
        "autoCompleteSearch" => array(
          "tokenizer" => "standard",
          "filter" => array("lowercase", "trim", "standard")
       )
    )
  )
),
'mappings' => array(
  "myindex" => array(
    'properties' => array(
      'Id' => array(
        'type'  => 'integer',
        'index' => 'not_analyzed'
      ),
      'Title' => array(
        'type'  => 'string',
        'fields'=> array(
          raw' => array(
            'type'  => 'string',
            "search_analyzer" => "autoCompleteSearch",
            'index' => 'not_analyzed'
          )
        )
      ),
      'Content' => array(
        'type'  => 'string',
        'fields'=> array(
          raw' => array(
            'type'  => 'string',
            "search_analyzer" => "autoCompleteSearch",
            'index' => 'not_analyzed'
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Here is the query:

```
"query" : {
  "query_string": {
    "query": "*t-shir red*",
    "lowercase_expanded_terms": false,
    "fields": [
       "Title.raw",
       "Content.raw"
     ]
   }
 }
```

I want to find T-shirt RED as I write in the search field for ex. "t-shirt red".

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Make your `.raw` field or create another sub-field (if you need `.raw` for something else) as `analyzed` with a `keyword` analyzer combined with `lowercase` filter. So that sub-field will keep the text as is, but lowercase it. And when using the `query_string` you should specify `Title.raw_lowercased`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this with the custom raw lowercased sub-field:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_keyword_lowercase_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "mappings": {
    "myindex": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "Title": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "raw_lowercase": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "my_keyword_lowercase_analyzer"
            }
          }
        },
        "Content": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "raw_lowercase": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "my_keyword_lowercase_analyzer"
            }
          }
        },
        "Image": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*t-shirt\\ red*",
      "lowercase_expanded_terms": false, 
      "fields": [
        "Title.raw_lowercase",
        "Content.raw_lowercase"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Andrei, I can search for lowercase strings. I just need to add php function strtolower when sending the string to the elastic search. Thank you again. Wish you all the best and I hope I will not have any problems again with the elastic search. And accept my apologize if my questions are easy or sth like that I just do not know how to use properly ES. Regards :)

Comment: `query_string` is not trivial ;-), don't worry.

Comment: Can you give me an advice how I can escape " (double quotes), I tried to add backslash but I constantly receive fatal error, when I am replacing " into \". Because I want to search for inches( " ) for ex. Laptop 15.6". The other reserved characters are fine  + - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ ~ * ? : \ / I can replace them without problems but " breaks.

Comment: Try with `\\"`. One `\` is for escaping the double quote itself inside a text with double quotes. The second `\` is for keeping the first `\` as is a [special character](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters).

Comment: Actually, I've tried both cases, the error is always there. I've used the plugin(for the elastic search) to test for valid JSON and it always expects "query": "*15\\-g092sa\\ 15.6\"*" <-- to be valid json; "query": "*15\\-g092sa\\ 15.6\\"*" <-- not valid json. What is really interesting for me is that the other special chars could be escaped with backslash but not the double quotes.